# Adding data to JSON array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "sender": "x",
      "message": "Placeholder",
      "date": "May 8, 2016 11:47:45 PM"
    }
    {
      "sender": "y",
      "message": "Yes",
      "date": "May 8, 2016 11:56:39 PM"
    },
    {
      "sender": "z",
      "message": "No",
      "date": "May 10, 2016 6:19:26 PM"
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the best practice to add object to messages array? Is there a standard way to do it?

Comment: Decode your json. Add the data. Encode it again.

Comment: `$myJSON = json_decode($string, true); $myJSON['messages'][] = array('sender' => '', 'message' => '', 'date' => ''); $string = json_encode($myJSON);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple, just convert (decode) the JSON into a PHP array, add the new message data, and re-encode it to a JSON string!

Sample Code:

```
$array = json_decode($inputJSON);
$array['messages'][] = ['sender'=>'sample', 'message'=>'sample', 'date'=>'sample'];
$jsonOutput = json_decode($array);
```